# Calling a c function in python

Tags: python, c

Basically I'm trying to call a c function using ctypes but when i do that i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reader.py", line 3, in <module>
    rf = CDLL(so_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/pi/rfid/rc522/rc522.so: undefined symbol: bcm2835_spi_setDataMode
```

I, to be honest, don't know the direction I need to go in to fix this.
The function i used to make the rc522.so file is:

```
cc -fpic -shared -o rc522.so main.c config.c rc522.c rfid.c value.c
```

The code in python is simply:

```
from ctypes import *
so_file = "/home/pi/rfid/rc522/rc522.so"
rf = CDLL(so_file)

rf.main.disp_card_details()
```

edit:
I commented the function out that was in the error and got the same error with a different function from the same library. So i know it has something to do with that library but I can't really comment away every mention of that library as my code kind of relies on that library.

edit2:
I solved the issue, i had to add the library itself to the cc.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong within the C code that you compiled. Not going to be possible to diagnose that from the Python side. First, try to make as simple of a hello-world example as you can. If that still doesn't work, post the complete example - enough that other people could reproduce the problem. If it does work, then it becomes a matter of adding stuff until you find the problematic part.

Comment: Okay so i just made a simple c function that prints hello and that works calling it using python. I think the problem lies somewhere in using the bcm2835 library but i don't know why. I have more than 1 reference to bcm2835 in my code and the bcm2835_spi_setDataMode is neither the first or the last reference. Is it maybe a good idea to check if i can get to the code in that library?

Comment: If it's not all your code, perhaps there's some documentation you can refer to, or an issue tracker, etc. ?